# Troubles capturing screen with winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I've been trying to capture the screen of my display using c++ and winapi to later convert it to a DIB for modifications. So far I've came up with this, in accordance with every guide out there:

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

void mainloop()
{ 
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    if (!hdcScreen)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't get DC for screen\n";
    }

    auto width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    auto height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);   

    HDC memDc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);  
    if (!memDc)
    {
        std::cout << "Create compatible DC failed!\n";
    }

    HBITMAP hScreenBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memDc, width, height);      
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    if (!hScreenBmp)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateCompatibleBitmap to screen failed\n";
    }
    SelectObject(memDc, hScreenBmp);

    if (!BitBlt(memDc,
        0, 0,
        width, height,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        std::cout << "BitBlt failed\n";
    }

    GetObject(hScreenBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    char* lpbitmap = (char*)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    GetDIBits(memDc, hScreenBmp, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    std::cout << "Lines: " << bi.biWidth << " x " << bi.biHeight << "px \n";
    char* currPixel = (char*)lpbitmap;
    for (auto j = 0; j < bi.biHeight; j++)
    {
        std::cout << "Line" << j << ":\n";
        for (auto i = 0; i < bi.biWidth; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "(" << std::to_string(static_cast<unsigned char>(currPixel[0])) << "," << std::to_string(static_cast<unsigned char>(currPixel[1]))
                << "," << std::to_string(static_cast<unsigned char>(currPixel[2])) << ")\t";
            currPixel += 4;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }  
  
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);
    DeleteDC(hdcScreen);
    DeleteDC(memDc);   

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Main loop completed in: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << "ms\n";
}

int main()
{
    mainloop();
}
```

(and also every other variation of the above I could think of). However, the loop at the ends tries to print the values of the pixels in the DIB - and, unfortunately, all come out zeros: "(0,0,0)...". Not sure what the problem may be here and I'd love some feedback that could shed some light on this. I should probably note that the screen has a resolution of 3820x2160 pixels so the memory allocation needed for the bitmap is rather large. Also, this is a terminal-type program and not a windows-one (maybe something is not properly configured/linked - dunno - just guessing). I also tried moving the BitBlt call to every possible spot but to no avail (not sure at which time it should be called for the desired effect). Thanks for the help!

Comment: You've posted the code that creates the bitmap, but it is just as likely that your bug is in the code that prints the pixel values, so I would show that as well. At first glance your bitmap creation code looks OK.

Comment: The double for loop, posted above, does the printing.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the device context of the desktop window?  I would have expected something like this `HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();` and get the device context of `desktop`.

Comment: Well, for the purposes of getting the bitmap I expect to not need the HWND of the desktop, since no function I use needs it (neither BitBlt nor GetDIBits). I expect only to use a HDC for the desktop, which I get through a call to GetDC(NULL) - supposedly giving it a NULL handle gets you the screen DC. I must note however, that I also tried `HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());`, `HDC hdcScreen = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL)` and possibly also something else I don't remember now.

Comment: Make a [mre]. Remove everything not needed and add the things that are.

Comment: Edited original post to oblige - that's actually more or less what I have.

Comment: I was able to get a valid bitmap with [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22556f21aaa4d5b8) -- (ignore the compilation errors).  Take that code as is, do not make any changes, compile it, and run it.  Since the device context is highly dependent on the display, I can't guarantee if it works for you, but it works ok for me.

Comment: Welp, thanks Paul - that seems to be working. However, as far as I can the tell the only difference with your code (apart the obnoxious return checks I have) is the CAPTUREBLT flag in BitBlt - but removing it also works. So what gives? Why does that work and my version doesn't. This is so weird (to me at least)

Comment: Ok, sec: another diference: I have `HBITMAP hScreenBmp =  CreateCompatibleBitmap(memDc, width, height);` where as your code `HBITMAP hScreenBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);` - got to look into that

Comment: According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap):Note: When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in CreateCompatibleBitmap, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used to create the memory device contex.

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT yes, that explains it - thanks

Comment: You can post an answer and mark yourself, this will be beneficial to other community.